# How to convert from float 32 to 8 bit without losing information?

Tags: python, opencv, contour, bounding-box, 8-bit

I tried to find contours in my image with `cv2.findContours`. So as it uses CV_8UC1 images I tried to convert my array with `dtype=np.uint8`, before it was 32 bit. But there I am loosing information. Is there any other way?

The second porblem is the bounding box. The informations are saved in `rect` but it is not draw in the picture. Does anyone know why?

Here is my picture/array in 32 bit:

[image]

And this is my picture when I added `dtype=np.uint8` :

[image]

```
img_hr = np.array(b[1],dtype=np.uint8)

img_hr=img_hr*255
plt.imshow(img_hr)

hierachy, img_threshold = cv2.threshold(img_hr, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(img_threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(img_threshold, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

for cnt in contours:         
      rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
      box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
      box = np.int0(box)
      cv2.drawContours(img_threshold,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
      cv2.circle(img_threshold,(int(rect[0][0]),int(rect[0][1])),5,(255,0,0),-1)

plt.imshow(img_threshold)
```

I hope you understand my problem. If not please ask. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question very well, but there's nothing stopping you finding contours using an 8-bit image and applying the contours back to your original 32-bit data when you have them.

Comment: My problem is, that I lose contours as shown in the pictures when I convert from 32 to 8 bit. I dont need to convert back to 32 bit.

Comment: When your data was 32-bit, what were the brightest and darkest pixels? And what were they after you converted to 8-bit?

Comment: 32 bit: min--> 6.723715e-20; max --> 255;
8 bit: min -->0;  max -->255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

First I used the 32-bit image to find the contours with `cv2.threshold` in the 32-bit image. After this I convert the 32-bit array to 8-bit `np.array(img_threshold_32bit,dtype=np.uint8)` without losing any contours.
So now the input for `cv2.drawContours` is an 8-bit array.

But I still have the problem that the bounding-box is not draw in the plot. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
img_hr = np.array(b[1])

hierachy, img_threshold_32bit = cv2.threshold(img_hr, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_8bit = np.array(img_threshold_32bit,dtype=np.uint8)
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(img_8bit, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img_8bit, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

for cnt in contours:
      rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
      box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
      box = np.int0(box)
      cv2.drawContours(img_8bit,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
      cv2.circle(img_8bit,(int(rect[0][0]),int(rect[0][1])),5,(255,0,0),-1)

plt.imshow(img_8bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you draw yourself
drawContours only draws contours outlines or filled contours.
you must be find a rectangle coords for each contour by using boundingRec or minAreaRect then draw it by using drawing functions of opencv

check this sample code
https://github.com/birolkuyumcu/opencvbook_python/blob/master/Ders6/Ders6.py#L114

Comment: I think that is what I did. As i said, I found the countours correctly with `minAreaRect` because my variable `rect` has the right values for the bounding box. And then I use `drawContours` but the bounding box is not shown in the image

Comment: drawContours ONLY  draws contours outlines or filled contours.

read code

to draw a rectangle you must be use cv2.rectangle function