# Bounding box is not shown in plot

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I tried to plot my image with the center point and the bounding-box. In the variable `rect` are the information for heigh, weidth, angle and center point, so I assume that the contours and everything is found correctly. But why is it not shown in the plot?

```
hierachy, img_threshold_32bit = cv2.threshold(img_hr, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_8bit = np.array(img_threshold_32bit,dtype=np.uint8)    
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(img_8bit, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)    
cv2.drawContours(img_8bit, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

for cnt in contours:         
      rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
      box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
      box = np.int0(box)
      cv2.drawContours(img_8bit,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
      cv2.circle(img_8bit,(int(rect[0][0]),int(rect[0][1])),5,(255,0,0),-1)

plt.imshow(img_8bit)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you're drawing a black rect, and probably you just don't see it. Try with a brighter tone of gray: `cv2.drawContours(img_8bit,[box],0,(200,0,0),2)`

Comment: No, `(0,0,255)` is red and `(255,0,0)` is blue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68295531/222216

Comment: since you're drawing on a 1 channel image, you should consider only the first channel. So (0, ..., ...) is black, and (255, ..., ...) is white. (200,...,...) is a light gray.

Comment: But  `drawContours` is independently from my chanels of the image. I only scale with the values in the brackets the color of the line of the bounding box. Check **https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc**. I also tried it your way and it doesnt work.

Comment: Try to draw and plot with your original BGR image (not with `img_8bit`) and let see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the image was binary, first I need to convert it back to 3 channels. After this the bounding box is shown correctly in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 3 channel image, so instead of `plt.imshow()` use

```
cv2.imshow("image name",img_8bit)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This worked for me as well. Hope this solves your problem.